# DapperDotNet w/IronPython: How To Handle Returned Result Set?

Tags: ironpython, dapper, dynamic-language-runtime

Tried to throw a quick example together this morning but I ran into a road block.  Everything works fine up to the point when I want to do something with the result set returned.  Dapper is returning a result set of System.Collections.Generic.List'1 back.  Can IronPython handle consuming generic collections of expando objects?

The gist of related code is here:  https://gist.github.com/3873014

Edit:  Ok, I've finally noticed I never told the Query extension a type.  Working on that now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After giving the Query extension a type, I was able get this working.  To test this out, I ended up just returning the results as a simple System.Object:

`data = cn.Query[object](procName, params,commandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure)[0]`

Converted to type to a dictionary:
`customer = clr.Convert(data, IDictionary[System.String, System.Object])`

And was able to get what I needed from there. So,...

`>>>print customer.CustomerID`

...returns 'ALKFI'.  Programmer error FTW!

Comment: Calling `Query(...)` actually gets the same objects as `Query<object>` - a sequence of `FastExpando` instances. You should be able to use just `Query(...)`, and (as you have above) just treat each as an `IDictionary<string,object>`. Or in shorter words, the `[object]` in `cn.Query[object]` is redundant. The reason for this is that `dynamic` doesn't actually exist; in C#, `dynamic` is a fancy word for `object`, but with some extra goo. As a consequence, `Query<object>` is indistinguishable from `Query<dynamic>`. So we treat `Query<object>` as "give me `FastExpando` instances".